# Call Javascript function with parameters inside PHP

Tags: php, javascript, function

I have a javascript function which has some parameters (an array). I want to call it inside php. Following is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

<?php 

$task_list=array();
        foreach($tasks as $row2){


            $task_list=$row2;
        }

         echo "display_diagram(".$task_list.");";

        ?>

function display_diagram(var1){

     .........................
     .........................

 }
```

When I call it without any parameter it is working (I could displayed the content in javascript function. But when I give the parameter( it is an array it dose not working. Could you give this a solution?

Comment: if this a .js file, then you cannot call php inside a .js file. You will have to insert the javascript into a php file for this to function.

Comment: No this is a .php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The usual practice here is to create a separate PHP file that outputs JSON data and fetch that data using an AJAX request. Below is an example of including JSON data inline, but I wouldn't typically recommend doing it like this, especially if the data is quite large.*

---

Use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) to convert a PHP variable into something that can be used in JavaScript. With an associative array, you'll get a JavaScript **object** like `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}`. With a non-associatve array, you'll get a JavaScript **array** like `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

```
<script>
<?php
    $tasks = array(
        145 => array(
            'name' => 'Sorting Task',
            'owner' => 'user1'
        ),
        2343 => array(
            'name' => 'Processing Task',
            'owner' => 'user2'
        ),
        7266 => array(
            'name' => 'Another Task',
            'owner' => 'user1'
        ),
        8373 => array(
            'name' => 'Lorem Ipsum Task',
            'owner' => 'user3'
        )
    );
    echo 'display_diagram(' . json_encode($tasks) . ')';
?>

function display_diagram(tasks) {
    $.each(tasks, function (id, task) {
        console.log('Task #' + id + ': name=' + task.name + ', owner=' + task.owner);
    });
}
</script>
```

The JavaScript above uses jQuery to process the object. It should output the following in the JavaScript console:

```
Task #145: name=Sorting Task, owner=user1
Task #2343: name=Processing Task, owner=user2
Task #7266: name=Another Task, owner=user1
Task #8373: name=Lorem Ipsum Task, owner=user3
```

Comment: How can I apply this for my scenario ?

Comment: Correct. Changing `$task_list` to `$tasks` was the thing to do. `$task_list` is not necessary.

Comment: I work for me, It is an asscociative array. How can I print it in the javascript?

Comment: @Malintha Updated again with an example of how you might process this in JavaScript. Of course it really depends on what `$tasks` looks like and what you want to do with it.